# JS mobile: how many memory I have available

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile, memory-management

I'm starting to develop mobile SPA with Flux and React. Wise people say that in memory usage matters. BUT, how many memory actually do I have?

Suppose user opened my app in browser, his mobile has 2GB of RAM. How many memory may use my app to not harm performance? What I should pay attention for? How will vary a speed depending on memory usage?

Actually I'm little bit misleading by the amount of RAM, and not able to imagine where memory may go.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid unnecessary data saving, loading unnecessary libraries. Minimize (uglify) your JS and CSS. Load data by chunks of 1000.

If you follow Flux, React and general front-end best practices, you shall be fine.

Comment: isn't caching in sake of performance - a "repetitive data saving"?

Comment: sorry, a wording issue. I meant to say 'avoid unnecessary data saving'. Caching is, of course, ok and recommended

Comment: do you mean that all memory/performance issues should be address only when they appear, not earlier?